# How to draw a polyline below a polygon?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polygon

How can I draw a polyline below a polygon in google maps javascript? I draw first the polygon and then the polyline and I don't want the line passing over the polygon, I want the polygon to be the top layer.

I create polygons and polylines like this:

```
new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: googleCoordinates,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: '#40FF00',
                strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                strokeWeight: 2
            });

new google.maps.Polygon({
                path: googleCoordinates,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                strokeWeight: 2
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#PolylineOptions
 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#PolygonOptions

Polylines and Polygons both have a zIndex property, I think that's what you're looking for:

```
new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: googleCoordinates,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: '#40FF00',
            strokeOpacity: 0.5,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            zIndex: 10
        });

new google.maps.Polygon({
            path: googleCoordinates,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.5,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            zIndex: 11
        });
```

In this example I set them to 10 and 11, you'll have to play around with those values as I don't know if they are limited to the map (I think so) or they will affect the zIndex of the polygon and polyline in the whole page.

Comment: Thanks. But I still see the below line draw on the top of the first one because the color changes (second line opacity 0.5, first one opacity 1). I will look for about that.

Comment: I think we're speaking about optics now, if you have to opaque objects one on top of the other you will always see both of them

Comment: I see in your code both have strokeOpacity set to 0.5, so both are opaque. This could be the issue

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, I thought I changed it. Thank you man!